# <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed for python2 but not in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I have a server (RHEL 7.5) with both python2 (2.7.5) and python3 (3.7.9)

When I run the below code it's passed successfully for python3 but failed for python2

```
try:   
    import urllib2 #python2
except:
    import urllib.request as urllib2 #python3

req = urllib2.Request('https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

for python3 I get the output

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f1688405850>
```

But for python2 the below error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)>
```

I don't want to disable the ssl verification.

What can be issue that python3 is working and failed on python2?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/  and Python 2 is EOL.

Comment: thanks, it's help me